# Do deferrable views only work inside standalone components?

Tags: angular, deferred-loading

I'm trying out deferrable views and have this code in the component of a normal (NgModule-based) component.

```
@defer (on interaction) {
    <app-defer></app-defer>
}@placeholder {
    <p>click to load</p>
}
```

The DeferComponent in the `@defer` block is standalone, but it is included in the initial bundle. The placeholder is shown until it is clicked, but no new content is loaded in after that. However, when I make the parent component standalone, the `@defer` block works as expected and the DeferComponent is not loaded in until the placeholder is clicked.

Is this expected? I'm confused about this because the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/defer#behavior-with-ngmodule) from Angular seems to indicate that only the components in the `@defer` block should be standalone in order for this to work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v17.2, yes deferrable views are only supported on standalone components.

The Angular team is looking to add support for non-standalone components in v18.
So wait & see.